# Upgrading Smooch from 3 to 4. When I get the messages, the user is Web User b0b0b2865ba9080d31d7894d instead of having the name

Tags: angularjs, initialization, chat, smooch

I use the latest version 4.13

This is my init:

```
var promise = Smooch.init({
                appId: smooch_key,
                givenName: $rootScope.data.user.first_name,
                surname: $rootScope.data.user.last_name,
                properties: {
                    email: $rootScope.data.user.email,
                    uid: $rootScope.data.user.id,
                    language: $rootScope.data.user.language,
                    country: $rootScope.data.user.country
                }
            });
            promise.then(function() {
                $('#sk-holder').addClass('no-print');
                $rootScope.smooch_inited = true;
            });
```

As you can see, I give it the name, but it seems to now work.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`givenName`, `surname`, and `properties` are not part of the supported [init parameters](https://github.com/smooch/smooch-web#initoptions). You should call [`Smooch.updateUser`](https://github.com/smooch/smooch-web#updateuseruser) to set the properties on the user record

```
Smooch.init({
    appId: smooch_key
})
    .then(function() {
        Smooch.updateUser({
            givenName: $rootScope.data.user.first_name,
            surname: $rootScope.data.user.last_name,
            properties: {
                email: $rootScope.data.user.email,
                uid: $rootScope.data.user.id,
                language: $rootScope.data.user.language,
                country: $rootScope.data.user.country
            }
        });

        $('#sk-holder').addClass('no-print');
        $rootScope.smooch_inited = true;
    });
```

Comment: yes, that is how I made it after checking the documentation. and now it works.